# Só recebo um checkbox no meu banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Estou a fazer um formulário com *PHP* e *HTML* em que ao marcar vários `checkbox` devo recebe-los e inserir no meu banco de dados.

Mas eu só consigo  receber um, por exemplo, se eu  assinalar 2 `chekbox` eu só vou receber o último `checkbox` selecionado, o que devo fazer para obter todos os selecionados?

**Meu `form.php` :**

```
<form method="POST" action="cadastra.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao" value="bom" />bom
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao" value="regular" />Regular
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao" value="inrregular" />Inrregular
  <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</form>
```

**Meu  `cadastrar.php`:**

```
$situacao = $_POST['situacao'];
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "form";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname); // faz a conexao

//INSERT INTO FORMULARIO SITUACAO = 
//ESCOLHE A TABELA SITUAÇAO  DA TABELA FORMULARIO
//VALUES('$SITUACAO') = RECEBE OS VALORES QUE TÊM  O NAME SITUAÇAO

$result_formulario = "INSERT INTO formulario(situacao) VALUES ('$situacao')"; 
$resultado_formulario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_formulario);
```

Comment: Posta o código, assim fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Na pergunta tu fala que é um checkbox, mas no código aparece um radio.

Comment: Você não consegue marcar mais de um radio button. Se fosse um checkbox até poderia. Se quer receber todos com o mesmo nome deixe assim `name="situacao[]"` e no php faça um foreach para obter os valores.

Comment: Ele tentou editar a pergunta para checkbox, mas a edição dele conflitou com a minha, acredito que o problema dele seja no PHP.

Comment: Checkbox com name repetido precisa de []

Answer (score 2):

Para cadastrar todos os campos marcados, tu precisa deixar os `inputs` como `arrays`, e então percorrer a variável para fazer a inserção de cada um.

Segue as modificações feitas no teu código:

HTML

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao[]" value="bom" />bom
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao[]" value="regular" />Regular
  <input type="checkbox" name="situacao[]" value="inrregular" />Inrregular
```

PHP

```
foreach($situacao as $s) {
    $result_formulario = "INSERT INTO formulario(situacao) VALUES ('$s')";
    $resultado_formulario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_formulario);
}
```

Comment: Eu colocaria um `if(!empty($_POST['situacao'])){ ... ` para o caso de nenhum checkbox ser marcador.